# Command.parameters.add - Running powershell in .Net

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm trying to find a way to run a powershell script / commands within a web page. After a short search over the internet I found System.management.Automation.I'm trying to run Powershell commands in C#. I wrote the following code and it works fine except I couldn't find how do I add the -recurse parameter of the copy-item command.

```
protected void ExecuteCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Clean the result textbox
    ResultBox.Text = string.Empty;

    //Create the runspace
    Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    runSpace.Open();

    //Create the pipeline
    Pipeline pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline();

    //Create the commands
    Command copyItem = new Command("copy-item");
    copyItem.Parameters.Add("Path", "c:\\temp\\");
    copyItem.Parameters.Add("Destination", "c:\\temp1\\");


    //robocopy.Parameters.Add("Dest", "c:\\temp1");
    pipeline.Commands.Add(copyItem);


    //Execute the script
    var results = pipeline.Invoke();

    //display results, with BaseObject converted to string
    if (results.Count > 0)
    {
        //We use a string builder on create our result text
        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var psobject in results)
        {
            //Convert the base object to a string and append it to the string builder.
            builder.Append(psobject.BaseObject.ToString() + "\r\n");

        }

        //Encode the string in HTML (Prevent security issue with 'dangerous' characters like <>)
        ResultBox.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(builder.ToString());
    }

    /*
    //Clean the result textbox
    ResultBox.Text = string.Empty;

    //Initialize Powershell Engine
    var powershellConsole = PowerShell.Create();

    //Add the script to the Powershell object
    powershellConsole.Commands.AddScript(Input.Text);

    //Execute the script
    var results = powershellConsole.Invoke();

    //display results, with BaseObject converted to string
    if (results.Count > 0)
    {
        //We use a string builder ton create our result text
        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var psobject in results)
        {
            //Convert the base object to a string and append it to the string builder.
            builder.Append(psobject.BaseObject.ToString() + "\r\n");

        }

        //Encode the string in HTML (Prevent security issue with 'dangerous' characters like <>)
        ResultBox.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(builder.ToString());
    }
   */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Switch` parameters (like `-Recurse`) are super easy to add - simply specify the parameter name and nothing else:

```
copyItem.Parameters.Add("Recurse");
```

That's it, nothing more to it :-)